# Angular + ng-repeat + индекс у элементво списка

Tags: angularjs

У меня вопрос по этому -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ангуляр понимает какой именно `$index` у элемента списка?

Answer (score 4):

директива [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) для каждого повторяемого элемента создает свой scope, в которые добавляет следующие служебные свойства

> **$index** - *число*   - индекс повторяемого элемента (0..length-1)
>   **$first**  - *булевское* - true если повторяемый элемент первый (index == 0).
>   **$middle** - *булевское* - true если повторяемый элемент между первым и последним.
>   **$last**   - *булевское* - true если повторяемый элемента последний (index == length-1).
>   **$even**   - *булевское* - true если позиция $index четная (иначе false).
>   **$odd**    - *булевское* - true если позиция $index нечетная (иначе false).

Так как функции вызываемые из view, вызываются в контексте *текущего* scope, а для каждого элемента создан свой собственный, при вызове

```
remove($index)
```

`$index` - будет браться из конкретного scope и иметь корректное значение.

Comment: спасибо. все страшнее и страшнее становится